# How to get information from database excluding some data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables in my database.

The first table is "Ordenes", in this table i have all the orders that the users create in the website, this table got information like: FechaFinal, FechaInicial, NoOrden, Cantidad, and Estado.

I have another table called "Cables", in this table i save all the cable that the users register per order.

For example, if i have a order row and the Cantidad says that is 200, so the user need register 200 cables to this order.

The Cables table have information like: Serial, IdOrden, and IdOperation.
The IdOperation is a foreign key of the Operations Tables, in this table i save information like: Name of operation, and its all.

So i want to do a sql query that show me this information:

FechaInicial (From Order Table), Fechafinal (From Order Table), NoOrden (From Order Table), Material (From Order Table), Cantidad (From Order Table), and Performed (This is a count of all cables that i have in my Cables Table for some Order)

I have it, and it works, but i want that the query ONLY COUNT the cables that doesn't are in some operation called 'Scrap'.

I have this SQL Query, and it works, but it also is counting the cables that are in the 'Scrap' Operation.

```
SELECT o.FechaInicial, o.FechaFinal, o.NoOrden, o.Material, o.Cantidad, COUNT(c.IdCable) as 'Hechos', o.Estado
FROM Ordenes o
LEFT JOIN Cables c ON o.IdOrden = c.IdOrden 
LEFT JOIN Operaciones op ON c.IdOperacion = op.IdOperacion AND op.Nombre NOT IN ('Scrap')
GROUP BY o.FechaInicial, o.Fechafinal, o.NoOrden, o.Material, o.Cantidad, o.Estado;
```

I want to show ALL orders, even if a order doesn't have cables yet.

Answer (score 1):

Change the count to `COUNT(op.Nombre)` or `COUNT(op.idOperacion)` if `Nombre` can be NULL.

Answer (score 0):

The `left join` keeps all rows, even those that have `scrap`.  The best solution is to count the primary key or join key from the last table.  So, I would recommend:

```
SELECT o.FechaInicial, o.FechaFinal, o.NoOrden, o.Material, o.Cantidad, 
       COUNT(op.IdOperacion) as Hecho, o.Estado
FROM Ordenes o LEFT JOIN 
     Cables c
     ON o.IdOrden = c.IdOrden LEFT JOIN
     Operaciones op
     ON c.IdOperacion = op.IdOperacion AND op.Nombre NOT IN ('Scrap')
GROUP BY o.FechaInicial, o.Fechafinal, o.NoOrden, o.Material, o.Cantidad, o.Estado;
```

This counts only "matching" rows in `Operaciones`.

Note:  If you count a data column, you might be missing rows where that value is `NULL` in the original table.  That might be a good thing, depending on the intention of the query.  In general, it is safer to count something that cannot be `NULL` when a match occurs.